# How to get all classes in current project using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I list all the classes in my current project(assembly?) using reflection? thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Given an instance `a` of System.Reflection.Assembly, you can get all types in the assembly using:

```
var allTypes = a.GetTypes();
```

This will give you all types, public, internal and private.

If you want only the public types, you can use:

```
var publicTypes = a.GetExportedTypes();
```

If you are running this code from within the Assembly itself, you can get the assembly using

```
var a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
```

GetTypes and GetExportedTypes will give you all types (structs, classes, enums, interfaces etc.) so if you want only classes you will have to filter

```
var classes = a.GetExportedTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass);
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [Assembly.GetTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) method.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you use the [Assembly.GetTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) method.