# Possibility to get all namespaces and classes of a project

Tags: c#, class, namespaces

I am quite new with C#(Visual Studio) and I hope I am asking a logical question: is that possible and how to get the information with all used namespaces and classes from a C# project?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949246/how-to-get-all-classes-within-namespace

Comment: If you just want to browse, you can also use Object Browser:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exy1facf(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @cherhan I believe op wants to get all namespaces and classes in a project, not all classes in a namespace..

Comment: Do you want to get it in a program or just view it?

Comment: In that case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318928/how-to-get-all-classes-in-current-project-using-reflection

Comment: thank you all for the answers! What I exactly want is 1. Step: I can at least view all namespaces and classes used in a projekt. 2. Step: I want to export this information to a, let's say, a file in text format. The question is, is that possible at all?

Comment: @cherhan I think it is the right solution to my question. thanks!