# exporting class names,method names given a namespace

Tags: c#, java, namespaces

How to export class names,method names given a namespace in c# without it being a part of that namespace/code to preferrably a txt file. The code should not be a part of the code whose classes, method names are to be retrieved.

Comment: Could you give us some code to see what you tried?

Comment: No am completely blank. Have not started to code.

Comment: Did you do any research on this topic?

Comment: found some pages that instruct to use reflection, assemblies. But couldn't get to understand them.

Comment: i guess a more elaborate reponse in this link would have helped. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318928/how-to-get-all-classes-in-current-project-using-reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reflection:

```
string ns = "System.Text";

var types = from asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            from type in asm.GetTypes()
            where type.Namespace == ns
            orderby type.Name
            select type;
foreach(var type in types)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", type.Name, type.Assembly.FullName);
    // and list the methods for each type...
    foreach (var method in type.GetMethods().OrderBy(x => x.Name))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", method.Name);
    }
}
```

Note that in the above I'm looking in all the loaded assemblies in the current app-domain; you can also just look in an individual assembly if appropriate.

Comment: This code works as intended. Thanks a lot. Any leads on how to save it as a text file?

Comment: `using(var output = File.CreateText()) {...}` and write to `output` instead of `Console` ?

Comment: And can you brief on how to use individual assembly?

Comment: Since this answer explained and worked with the "System.Text" namespace i added reference to another project and gave its namesapce in ns. But not working. where am i going wrong??

Comment: @cooltoad to use an individual assembly you could start with `from type in typeof(SomeTypeYouKnow).Assembly.GetTypes()`, where `SomeTypeYouKnow` is in the assembly you are talking about. The reason it isn't working currently is that nothing is *loading* the assembly you are talking about. The `typeof` will force it to be loaded.

Comment: I have exported it as a text file... But i also need to do the same in java. Any leads ?