# Finding the public classes in a directory of files

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

I know using reflection that I can find the list of classes within a single assembly (such an example is [How to get all classes in current project using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318928/how-to-get-all-classes-in-current-project-using-reflection)).

Is there a way to do this with just public classes within a given directory?

Comment: What is "*a directory*"? Are you referring to an actual folder on your system?

Comment: for example, my project has a directory called "fun_classes" which contains a pile of SQL classes for the creation of tables. I'd be looking to examine that directory and extract the class names - can equally apply to any directory though.

Comment: I deleted my answer since the link you included does actually include an answer that looks for public classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean a directory that contains one or more assemblies, if so you can do it like this:

```
var types = new List<Type>();

var paths = Directory.GetFiles("directoryPath", "*.dll", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

foreach(var path in paths)
{
    types.AddRange(Assembly.LoadFrom(path).GetTypes());
}
```

`GetTypes` method uses `BindingFlags.Public` and `BindingFlags.Instance` by default.So you don't need to specify `BindingFlags` parameter additionally.